# Does ng-include have memory-leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, angularjs

I use `ng-include` to switch different data pages which will do a lot of data rendering.

I found the memory usage of the browser keeps growing, and never fall back.

### code

The code is quite simple.

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <button ng-click="url='nodata.html'">No data</button>
    <button ng-repeat="i in getNumArray(10)" ng-click="loadData(i)">Load data {{i}}</button>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  [{{url}}]
  <div ng-include="url"></div>
</body>
```

It will show a "no data" button, and 10 data buttons to load different pages.

The angular code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.url = "nodata.html";
  $scope.loadData = function(n) {
    $scope.url = "data" + n + ".html";
  }

  $scope.getNumArray = function(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i =0;i<n;i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  }
});

app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data;
  })
});
```

And the "dataN.html" pages:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  <table ng-repeat="x in getNumArray(500)">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{data["key0"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key1"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key2"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key3"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key4"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key5"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key6"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key7"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key8"]}}</td>
        <td>{{data["key9"]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The "nodata.html" page:

```
<div>No data yet.</div>
```

And the "data.json":

```
{
  "key0": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key1": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key2": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key3": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key4": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key5": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key6": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key7": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key8": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f",
  "key9": "sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sd fds fds fsd fds fds fds fds fsd fds fds f"
}
```

### Here is a live demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KGZVXIBws1kthgN2bxEJ?p=preview

When I open the live demo with chrome, the initialize memory usage is less than 100M. Then I click the "Load data" buttons, it will soon grow to 300M and never fall back, even if I click "No data" button to load the "nodata.html".

Is it normal? Does the `ng-include` have memory leak or do I missing anything? Or the memory usage is just fine that I don't need to worry about it?

### screencast

I created a screencast to show it:

[image: ng-include]

Comment: Are you using the chrome extension [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)? 
It tends to make angular apps with large data, behave very slow. Also try running this on a window on it's own. Plnkr.co is not that great with memory

Comment: I installed `Angular Batarang`, but not enabled it. I also tried with clean chrome and firefox, both have the same issue. I use plnkr.co to make it easy to demo this issue, you can download the source code to test on you own computer.

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading to version 1.0.5.  It doesn't appear to have this problem.
I believe it is because there was a memory leak in 1.0.3/4 when there were top level white-space nodes in templates.

Comment: Still have the same problem even if I use 1.0.5. I just tried it in chrome, the memory quickly grows to 300M

Comment: Not on my machine. Are you still running in Pnkr?

Comment: Try running it separately.

Comment: I just tried, it has the same issue in a separated chrome (version:  26.0.1410.5)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Chrome on Windows. Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not the place to file a bugs. Please file the issue at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues and continue the discussion there.

I have simplified the use case into single file: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wm4YRsLGJUDqUcww2DQZ?p=preview

Here is what I found out.

1. Only leaks on Windows, does not leak on Mac OS X
2. Only leaks in plunker. When I run it outside the plunker it works fine.

Can you reproduce the issue outside the plunker?

Comment: you can run the app outside of plunker by going to: http://run.plnkr.co/3SWA4CzwnyKQyGXm/

Comment: the app doesn't leak outside of plunker (using link above) and with Chrome Canary on Windows (Version 27.0.1436.1 canary)

Comment: It's leaked even if I run it in a separated plunker (chrome version:  26.0.1410.5)